# GCP instances disappear after account/billing upgrade

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, instance, billing

I have four projects running in my GCP, each with a compute instance. When the free credits ran out, I was asked to upgrade my account and billing info. I took me few months to do that. But now that I did the upgrade, all instances have disappeared.

Is there a time frame required by GCP to upgrade, otherwise the instances are deleted?

Thanks,
Sherjeel

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a time frame required by GCP to upgrade, otherwise the instances are deleted?

When you run out of free credits, in other words, your **trial ends**, the resources you created during the trial are stopped.

As stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#end), when your trial ends, the following conditions apply:

- You must upgrade to a paid account to continue using Google Cloud.
- All resources you created during the trial are stopped.
- Any **data you stored in Compute Engine is lost**.
- Your account enters a **30-day grace period**, during which you can recover resources and 
  data you stored in any Google Cloud services during the trial period.

You might receive a message stating that your account has been canceled, which only indicates that your account has been suspended to prevent charges.

Furthermore, as shown [here:](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#recovering_data)

> Within that 30-day period, you can also contact [Google Billing Support](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing) to export any data you stored in Google GCP services (other than on [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/)). After 30 days, your data and resources are not available, even if you upgrade.

If you would like to know more details, you can find it at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/frequently-asked-questions#after-end).

I hope this helps.